# Ringing Effect in ideal low pass filter

Tags: image-processing, signals, filtering

What are the actual reasons for **Ringing effect** in *Ideal low/high pass filter* ? How *Gaussian low pass filter* removes it ?

Comment: I am a undergraduate student just studying image processing for the first time in my life.This is a short question for our exam. I just need answers just 3/4 lines, that's it. please help me. if it is not worthy here, let me know.I will delete this at once. thank you very much.

Comment: it is usually expected that you do some own research. which you obviously didn't do as your question is answered in the introduction of the respective wikipedia article. you may though ask questions if you don't understand a particular statement in such a source. many people will find that your question is off-topic as it is not a programming problem but more a mathematical question

Comment: This question is more suited for [SP-SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll just cite [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringing_artifacts) as I'm not willing to write a scientific publication on ringing.

And to your question: Gaussian low pass doesn't "remove" ringing. It doesn't cause ringing.

> The main cause of ringing artifacts is due to a signal being
>   bandlimited (specifically, not having high frequencies) or passed
>   through a low-pass filter; this is the frequency domain description.
>   In terms of the time domain, **the cause of this type of ringing is the
>   ripples in the sinc function** which is the impulse response (time
>   domain representation) of a perfect low-pass filter. Mathematically,
>   this is called the Gibbs phenomenon.
>
> In the time domain, the cause is an impulse response that oscillates,
>   assuming negative values. This can be resolved by using a filter whose
>   impulse response is non-negative and does not oscillate, but shares
>   desired traits. For example, for a low-pass filter, the **Gaussian
>   filter is non-negative and non-oscillatory, hence causes no ringing.**
>   However, it is not as good as a low-pass filter: it rolls off in the
>   passband, and leaks in the stopband: in image terms, a Gaussian filter
>   "blurs" the signal, which reflects the attenuation of desired higher
>   frequency signals in the passband. A general solution is to use a
>   window function on the sinc filter, which cuts off or reduces the
>   negative lobes: these respectively eliminate and reduce overshoot and
>   ringing. Note that truncating some but not all of the lobes eliminates
>   the ringing beyond that point, but does not reduce the amplitude of
>   the ringing that is not truncated (because this is determined by the
>   size of the lobe), and increases the magnitude of the overshoot if the
>   last non-cut lobe is negative, since the magnitude of the overshoot is
>   the integral of the tail, which is no longer canceled by positive
>   lobes.